# Get ACF-fields into CF7 as mail tags?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I have a wordpress website which announces courses on a regular basis, using posts. Any vistor can apply for the course directly on the post page (by typing in name, adress, phone, mail, etc.) via the Contact Form 7-plugin. I then get the information directly to my mail, and can call up the visitor and confirm the booking.

Previously I have used the special mail tag `[_post_url]` - so I know which course they are interested in.

Now, to make things more structured for both visitors and myself, I have added a three custom fields with the Advanced Custom Fields-plugin, for my posts.

```
<?php the_field('course-date'); ?>    
<?php the_field('course-type'); ?>
<?php the_field('course-location'); ?>
```

One field is a date picker, one is for price and the last one is for location. This works really great and looks good in a post.

But the problem is - I would like to get the information that I fill into the custom fields - as a "mail tag", so the date, price and location also are sent to my mail via the Contact Form 7 formula.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module for Contact Form 7 allows you to set hidden fields based on custom field values: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/